# How should I unit test Java that calls a MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing

I'm writing a simple application that will read some records and insert them in a database.  I've written a stored procedure that handles the insertion logic, and plan to test that separately.  Now I'd like to write a good unit test for the portion of the logic that takes a business object and passes it to the stored procedure call.

I *think* what I want to do is pass a mock of the database connection, then assert that the call is made with expected parameter values:

```
Connection dbConnection = makeMockConnection();  // how?
MyObjectWriter writer = new MyObjectWriter(dbConnection);
writer.write(someSampleObject);
// somehow assert that dbConnection called
// `sp_saveMyObject` with param values x, y, and z
```

However, it seems like a lot of work dig around inside `java.sql.Connection`, understand how it works, then mock all the results.  Is there a test library that does all this for me?  Am I coming at this the wrong way?

Comment: Mocking the connection to check if a method is called is really easy. You should get familiar with [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid constraining the business logic to run a certain way -- I could call `Connection.createStatement` or `Connection.prepareStatement` or `Connection.prepareCall` or even `Connection.nativeSql`, any of which is *correct* (in that the data gets passed to the procedure).  I'm trying to avoid having to mock out *all* of those things, or at least having to write those mocks myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an in-memory HSSQL database with a mock stored procedure. 
The mock sproc would insert a row into a table to show that it ran and what it's parameters were. 
Run the code under test and then look in the db to see what happened.

Comment: How much overhead does this create in running tests?  Right now the rest of my tests can run in a few milliseconds -- is the standup / teardown time significant?

Comment: I've never timed it but I'd guess a few 10s of ms due to the temporary files it creates. If you only had a handful of these type tests you wouldn't worry. If you had thousands you might. You could always share the same db instance over a number of tests as long as you cleaned up the table between them.  I use in memory dbs for testing an awful lot and find the simplicity win far outweighs the execution time. You don't have to change any code just pass in a different jdbc connection string. that's a huge advantage.

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble finding a simple guide to getting started with this -- the HSQLDB documentation is hundreds of pages, and most of the blog posts, etc, that I can find about unit testing with HSQLDB are specific to Hibernate / Spring.  I just need to start a database, add a table and a stored procedure, then tear it down when I'm done.  That should be easy, right?

Comment: Include the jar in your project and register the jdbc driver. Make up a database name(e.g. mytestdb) and jdbc connection string (jdbc:h2:target/mytestdb). When you connect via jdbc the database will be created automatically. Then use ddl commands through the jdbc api to create tables, sprocs, insert data etc.

Comment: java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.h2.Driver()); 

java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:target/mytestdb", "test", "test");

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Decorator design pattern for the connection mocking. You create a real Connection to the DB with the driver you use which is wrapped by your ConnectionImpl class that implements Connection interface and holds the real Connection as a member. 
Every real call that you don't want to actually do, replace it with a mock code, and every call the stays call the real connection object's identical method (Delegate the call).

In this way you are coding as usual, only differ in the returned object from the method that creates the connection.

Now, in the mock object (your ConnectionImpl) you can add unit testing code that checks input, for example.

Comment: The problem here is that, as I say in my comment on the OP, I'm trying not to dig into the guts of the Connection.  The wrapper would have to know *what* to check, what point in the execution is common between the 4 or 5 different ways of accomplishing the same thing.  Way, way more work than @AutomatedMike's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned with how `MyObjectWriter` works, just that it does, then I would be inclined to write an integration test and forget about a unit test.

You don't mention how you're testing the stored procedure, so forgive me, but what I would do is write tests around `MyObjectWriter` which invoke the actual stored-procedure on a database and then verify the database state afterwards. I would use an in-memory database, if possible, to keep test durations down.